# scraping news.google.com adds hl and ceid parameter as en-us when Im trying to query as for other country locale es-es

Tags: html, go, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape news.google.com for queries at the bottom on high hand side. My script works fine with en-us but when I try adding different locales it still gives en-us queries. My browser is assigning ceid and hl parameter by default to be en-us.

```
    package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
)

// difference returns the elements in `a` that aren't in `b`.
func difference(a, b []string) []string {
    mb := make(map[string]struct{}, len(b))
    for _, x := range b {
        mb[x] = struct{}{}
    }
    var diff []string
    for _, x := range a {
        if _, found := mb[x]; !found {
                diff = append(diff, x)
        }
    }
    return diff
}

func APIResponseRequest(locale string) []string{

    var queries []string
    stopWords := []string {"Google apps", "Top stories", "U.S.", "World",
        "Your local news", "Business", "Technology", "Entertainment", "Sports", "Science", "Health",
        "Get the Android app", "Get the iOS app", "Help", "Get perspectives and context", "Google", "",}
    // Instantiate default collector
    c := colly.NewCollector(
        // Visit only domains: news.google.com
        colly.AllowedDomains("news.google.com"),
    )
    // On every a element which has href attribute call callback
    c.OnHTML("a", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        link := e.Attr("aria-label")
        if link != "" {
            fmt.Println("printing queries ", link)
            queries = append(queries, string(link))
        }
    })

    // Before making a request print "Visiting ..."
    c.OnRequest(func(r *colly.Request) {
        r.Headers.Set("ceid", "es:es")
        fmt.Println("Visiting", r.URL.String())
    })

    // Start scraping on news.google.com
    u := "https://news.google.com"
    server, err := url.Parse(u)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    q := server.Query()
    q.Add("pz", "1")
    q.Add("hs",locale)
    q.Add("gl",locale)
    q.Add("ceid", strings.Replace(locale, "-",":", -1))
    server.RawQuery = q.Encode()
    c.Visit(server.String())
    diff_queries := difference(queries, stopWords )
    return diff_queries
}

func newshandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    locale_queryset := make(map[string]interface{})
    countries_supported  := []string{"es-es","de-de"}
    //countries_supported  := []string{"en-us"}
    for _, locale := range(countries_supported){
        queries := APIResponseRequest(locale)
        //fmt.Println(locale, ":",  queries)
        locale_queryset[locale] = queries
    }
    fmt.Println(locale_queryset)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(locale_queryset)
}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/api/gnews", newshandler)
    fmt.Println("Listening at http://localhost:8000/api/gnews")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
}
```

The URL I am expecting to scrape is : https://news.google.com?ceid=es%3Aes&gl=es-es&hs=es-es&pz=1
when I click on it: https://news.google.com/topstories?ceid=US:en&gl=US&hs=es-es&pz=1&hl=en-US
And I still get news queries from en-us itself.

How to add header saying that only the locale es-es results should be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Actually adding hl as parameter and using locale as value worked and I was able to get news queries from different queries.

Just added this line: 
`q.Add("hl",locale)`

I am not sure what these parameters are? Anyone have idea what these mean?